# можно ли скачать файлы с github, если они были добавлены в gitignore

Tags: git, github

Суть такая, я на одном ПК загрузил файлы в репозитарий, часть файлов была добавлены в gitignore, теперь мне нужно загрузить все файлы на другой ПК обычные и те которые в игноре, можно ли это сделать ?

Comment: Можно. gitignore не влияет на уже хранящиеся файлы.

Comment: Если ты их видишь на сайте, то их можно скачать. Если не видишь, значит нельзя. Очень просто.

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно.

Файл списки игнорирования (файл `.gitignore`, файл `.git/info/exclude`, параметр конфигурации `core.excludesfile`) влияют только на команды, обрабатывающие ещё не версированные (untracked) файлы. К таким командом относятся, например, `git status` и `git add *`.

Если файл попал в коммит, то список игнорирования на него никак не влияет.